# How to run the pg_relation_filepath-function on the remote PostgreSQL cluster?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have a PostgreSQL cluster on the server  10.10.10.1  and a test database 'PG114' with
the test table 'dbo.emp_t1'.

Working with the cluster I can execute:

SELECT pg_relation_filepath ( 'dbo.emp_t1' );

I am getting the following results:

pg_tblspc/16394/PG_11_201809051/16395/3978415

Now I am working with a PostgreSQL cluster on another server  10.10.10.2 .

I would like to connect to the cluster on the first server  10.10.10.1  (for instance
with the use of dblink-extention) and get the same information about the same table
or object 'dbo.emp_t1'.

What is the best way to run such a task?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty straightforward composition of two different features.  The hardest part about it is the need to have nested quote marks, which I handle here by using dollar quoting for one level.  I've used my own IP address and table name rather than yours, so that I can verify it works:

```
select * from dblink(
   'host=192.168.0.14',
    $$SELECT pg_relation_filepath ( 'public.j' )$$
) f(x text);
```